# Setting up nib and bootstrap-stylus

Tags: node.js, stylus

I've been playing around with node using jetbrains webstorm IDE. Last night I was trying to setup nib and bootstrap-stylus. However I always get an error that nib or bootstrap cant be found in the import tags.

```
@import 'nib'
```

or

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```

however if i use

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-stylus/lib/bootstrap'
```

everything works as expected. I don't think this is the right way? there must be some way to tell stylus where to look for imports?

my app.js looks like this

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var nib = require('nib');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-stylus');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('compress', true)
        .use(nib());
}

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    , compile: compile
}));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
```

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as rewriting your `compile()` function as follows:

```
function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('compress', true)
        .use(nib())
        .use(bootstrap()); // each plugin has to be loaded
}
```

More information about plugin usage and stylus can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jenius/8263065
And in the official documentation: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html#usefn